# Problem enabling CORS on nginx, request problems

Tags: vue.js, nginx, cors

I have an application where i make an auth to log in
In localhost, it performs well, but when we change to a server using a proxy, I receive an error saying to enable cors.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://projetos.dev.esppglobal.com:8080/dados/autentica?email=admin@admin.com&senha=admin' from origin 'http://projetos.dev.esppglobal.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I tried to follow https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html but the problem is the same.

my nginx.config is:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;

        server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /opt/webserver/admin/public/;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     } 

        }
        }
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are accessing a different port for your xhr request (8080), [CORS rules are in effect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors). It is simple to get around this using standard nginx rules.

I have been using something like this for a wide open CORS config:

```
 #
 # Wide-open CORS config for nginx
 # See https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html
 #

 if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    #
    # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
    #
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Phpsessid,X-gs-session,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
    #
    # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
    #
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
    add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
    return 204;
 }
 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
 add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-Phpsessid,X-gs-session,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
 add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-Phpsessid,X-gs-session,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
```

And then in your relevant location block, add:

```
include cors_params;
```

This is not safe to use for general purposes, though. If you know the origins that will access this page, then use the following line instead:

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://projetos.dev.esppglobal.com';
```